# Is it possible to get a pointer to a boxed unmanaged value type?

Tags: c#, pointers, boxing

Is it possible to get a pointer to a boxed unmanaged value type, without writing a large switch statement that does a cast for every supported type? Something like:

```
object val;         // Contains a boxed unmanaged value, such as int, long, byte, etc.
void* ptr = &val;   // Obviously does not compile
DoStuffWithPointer(ptr);
```

instead of

```
object val;   // Contains a boxed unmanaged value, such as int, long, byte etc.
if (val.GetType() == typeof(byte)) 
{
    var typedValue = (byte)value;
    DoStuffWithPointer(&typedValue);
}
else if (val.GetType() == typeof(short)) 
{
    var typedValue = (short)value;
    DoStuffWithPointer(&typedValue);
}
else 
    // ... and so on
```

Btw. I know the pointer points to a local variable on the stack, and will become invalid once the function returns. That's fine.

Comment: Why do you need pointers in the first place?

Comment: You can use `Unsafe.AsPointer<T>`. Should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ref T Unsafe.Unbox<T>(object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.unbox?view=net-7.0) to get **managed** pointer (`ref T`) to the boxed value.
Getting unmanaged pointer (`void*`/`IntPtr`) to boxed value is really a race with GC, unless you have pinned the box with `GCHandle`, so you can use
[`IntPtr GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject?view=net-7.0)
(or shoot yourself into the leg via `T* Unsafe.AsPointer<T>(ref T)`).

**(!)** Read carefully *Remarks* section on `Unsafe.Unbox`: You are not allowed to directly mutate contained value (you can only call properties/methods on it), use [`StrongBox<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1?view=net-7.0) / `OneOf<T1, T2, ...>` like classes, if you need to change the value.

---

> Btw. I know the pointer points to a local variable on the stack, and will become invalid once the function returns. That's fine.

Seems like you are ok with coping value from box to stack, then you can just use concise switch syntax:

```cs
switch (val)
{
    case int  typedValue: DoStuffWithPointer(&typedValue); break;
    case byte typedValue: DoStuffWithPointer(&typedValue); break;
    // ...
}
```